# Formatting label in SSRS for MB, GB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am attempting to create an SSRS report from a table that collects daily database stats (FileSize, Free Space). 
I am creating a graph within SSRS, which allows for multiple selections of databases across multiple server. I would like to format the chart label. The
formula currently looks like this:= `IIF (MAX(Fields!ID.Value) > 1024, Format((MAX(Fields!ID.Value)/1024), "#,0.0 GB"), Format(Fields!ID.Value,"#,0.0 GB"))`

However, this gives me this
[image: following] 
when I run it for a single database that has a size of 116973 MB.

Basically I cna run this for multiple databases, one which may have a size in MB, other which may have a size in GB. I would like the labels to account for that. What am I missing or doing wrong.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
left(ServerName, len(ServerName)-1) as servername,
DatabaseName,
SUM(FileSizeMB),
PollDate
 from DBInfo
 Where DatabaseName IN (@Database) AND left(ServerName, len(ServerName)-1)  IN (@Servers)
 AND PollDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
 GROUP BY ServerName, DatabaseName, PollDate
 Order BY PollDate
```

Original size is calculated in GB.

Comment: Your expression is referencing the `ID` field, but I don't see that column in your query. You should alias the `FileSizeMB` aggregate in the query so that the name comes through on your report dataset. Is the `ID` field what you renamed the aggregate to in the report?

Comment: By default since i am using the SUM(FileSizeMB) and have not created any alias for it, it has referenced it as ID field.